# What's currently the best way to pass data from a given content item to a variable Form in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I have a **product package** with several options in my Orchard site and I need users to be able to send an enquire **based on a single option**:

[image]

I've seen out there many articles about Tokens, Dynamic Forms (the examples using Dynamic Forms seem to be just for a single form type), I can think of many ways to achieve this but I don't know what is really the cleanest and fastest way to implement this functionality. 
I would need a hint on what to keep researching to speed this up.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your view, I'd wrap the button around an `<a>` tag something like this:

```
<a href="@(String.Format("/{0}/{1}", "x", y))" target="_blank">
    //put button code or whatever here
</a>
```

Where 'x' is the extended url and y could be the query string such as: www.google.com/game/q=2

When you do this and get the redirect correct, in your driver for the page, you can get the page number from the url using something like this:

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.Current();
var query = httpContext.Request.QueryString["q"];
```